# Unable to install RabbitMQ on Raspbian (Buster) because Erlang isn't the correct version, even though it says it's up to date

Tags: rabbitmq, erlang, debian, raspbian

I'm quite new to Raspberry Pi and Linux/Debian, so please bear with me. I have been trying for hours now to install rabbitMQ on my Raspberry Pi 3, to no avail. I followed the steps, but in the end I just get this whenever I try to write `sudo apt-get install rabbitmq-server` :

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 rabbitmq-server : Depends: erlang-base (>= 1:21.3) but 1:21.2.6+dfsg-1 is to be installed or
                            erlang-base-hipe (>= 1:21.3) but it is not installable or
                            esl-erlang (>= 1:21.3) but it is not installable
                   Depends: erlang-crypto (>= 1:21.3) but 1:21.2.6+dfsg-1 is to be installed or
                            esl-erlang (>= 1:21.3) but it is not installable
                   Depends: erlang-eldap (>= 1:21.3) but 1:21.2.6+dfsg-1 is to be installed or
                            esl-erlang (>= 1:21.3) but it is not installable
                   Depends: erlang-inets (>= 1:21.3) but 1:21.2.6+dfsg-1 is to be installed or
                            esl-erlang (>= 1:21.3) but it is not installable
                   Depends: erlang-mnesia (>= 1:21.3) but 1:21.2.6+dfsg-1 is to be installed or
                            esl-erlang (>= 1:21.3) but it is not installable
                   Depends: erlang-os-mon (>= 1:21.3) but 1:21.2.6+dfsg-1 is to be installed or
                            esl-erlang (>= 1:21.3) but it is not installable
                   Depends: erlang-parsetools (>= 1:21.3) but 1:21.2.6+dfsg-1 is to be installed or
                            esl-erlang (>= 1:21.3) but it is not installable
                   Depends: erlang-public-key (>= 1:21.3) but 1:21.2.6+dfsg-1 is to be installed or
                            esl-erlang (>= 1:21.3) but it is not installable
                   Depends: erlang-runtime-tools (>= 1:21.3) but 1:21.2.6+dfsg-1 is to be installed or
                            esl-erlang (>= 1:21.3) but it is not installable
                   Depends: erlang-ssl (>= 1:21.3) but 1:21.2.6+dfsg-1 is to be installed or
                            esl-erlang (>= 1:21.3) but it is not installable
                   Depends: erlang-syntax-tools (>= 1:21.3) but 1:21.2.6+dfsg-1 is to be installed or
                            esl-erlang (>= 1:21.3) but it is not installable
                   Depends: erlang-tools (>= 1:21.3) but 1:21.2.6+dfsg-1 is to be installed or
                            esl-erlang (>= 1:21.3) but it is not installable
                   Depends: erlang-xmerl (>= 1:21.3) but 1:21.2.6+dfsg-1 is to be installed or
                            esl-erlang (>= 1:21.3) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

After seeing this, I realize that my Erlang wasn't the correct version, and needs to be 1:21.3, instead of 1:21.2, so I went to go and update it, but it then says:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo apt-get install erlang
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
erlang is already the newest version (1:21.2.6+dfsg-1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

I looked on the Erlang web site and it just says write `apt-get install erlang` to make it work, but for some reason it just wants to stay at version 1:21.2.6, instead of the 22.2 that seems to be a latest version. Does anyone have any advice?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After Franva's comment, I have improved my answer.

Go to the page: https://www.rabbitmq.com/install-debian.html#manual-installation
Search for "Manual Installation with Dpkg" in the page and you will find the download link.
At the moment (4th June 2020) the file is "rabbitmq-server_3.8.4-1_all.deb"
Download that file and move it into the raspberry pi.

Go to the page: https://www.erlang-solutions.com/resources/download.html
and download the latest version for raspbian buster.

Then in Raspbian type

```
sudo apt-get remove erlang*
```

Then install the erlang package you have downloaded from the erlang website using

```
sudo dpkg -i name_of_the_erlang_package.deb
```

Install the RabbitMQ package you have downloaded from the RabbitMQ website using

```
sudo dpkg -i rabbitmq-server_3.8.4-1_all.deb
```

When the installation is over type the following commands:

```
sudo systemctl enable rabbitmq-server
sudo systemctl start rabbitmq-server
sudo rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management
```

Since the default user (guest) accesses to the web management console only from localhost, you can either log in from your raspberry and from chromium type

```
http://localhost:15672
```

and login with
user: guest
pass: guest
You can then create your own user and log in with it remotely

OR create your own user with the following commands

```
sudo rabbitmqctl add_user your_username your_password
sudo rabbitmqctl set_user_tags your_username administrator
sudo rabbitmqctl set_permissions -p / your_username ".*" ".*" ".*"
```

and connect to the management console from your browser using
    http://ip_of_the_raspberry:15672

Comment: works for me and even easier than the official instruction.... btw, I removed my broken mqtt-server, this is the only 1 extra step I did.

Comment: I just found out that the RabbitMQ installed this way is a very old version: 3.7.8 with Erlang 21.2.6 . I cannot even connect to the RabbitMQ server with my Mqtt Dash(Android app). Could you please help?

Comment: Edited my answer to support Franva

Answer (score 0):

I installed this way and it worked -

```
sudo apt-get install rabbitmq-server
sudo rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management
```